# Codeigniter RESTful API - {"status":false,"error":"Unknown method."}

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, rest

I've managed to setup the RESTful API in my Codeigniter Application. Now I want to get some data from my MySQL database, so in my Codeigniter models folder I have created a model called category_model.php:

```
<?php
  Class category_model extends CI_Model {
      var $table_name = 'category';

     function get_all_categories()
     {
       $this->db->select('*');
       $this->db->from($this->table_name);
       return $this->db->get();
     }
 }
?>
```

Then in the Codeigniter controller-folder I created a category.php file:

```
<?php

 include(APPPATH.'libraries/REST_Controller.php');

 class Category extends REST_Controller {

  function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('category_model');
    }

  function category_get()
    {
        $data = $this->category_model->get_all_categories();
        $this->response($data);
    }

 }

?>
```

Now, when I enter `http://localhost/myproejcts/ci/index.php/category/category` - I get the error `{"status":false,"error":"Unknown method."}` ??

what is the issue?

**[UPDATE]** = I get the same error when setting `function index_post()`

Comment: It's saying the method (category) cannot be found. Are you sure the server request method is get? You can check by doing $this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD')

Comment: Shouldn't it be `index_get()` instead of `category_get()`? Based on https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver#handling-requests

Comment: @AndréDion `index_get()` doesnt work.. i get more serious errors I dont get...

Comment: @foxmulder The check doesnt give me anything... unless i checked the wrong place? I checked inside category_get() function...

Comment: Anyone? I'm running out of ideas?

Comment: Name your function something else (not the same name as your controller) ... function my_action_get()

Comment: @foxmulder Unfortunately your suggestion didnt work... :-/

Comment: @SHT can you solve your problem?

Answer (score 7):

Depends of your HTTP request to your controller "Category" it will call related method:

```
public function index_get()
{   
    echo "GET_request";
}   

public function index_post()
{
    echo "POST_request";
}

public function index_put()
{
    echo "PUT_request";
}

public function index_patch()
{
    echo "PATCH_request";
}

public function index_delete()
{
    echo "DELETE_request";
}
```

So, rename your method to 'index_get'

Answer (score 4):

I think your problem is the name of controller is the same with the name of method try to make a test:

if the name of your controller is:

```
class Test extends CI_Controller{
    //your method name is different from the name of controller class
    public function testget_get(){ 
        echo $this->response(array('test'=> 'test'), 200);
    }
}
```

I have experienced this problem on hmvc structure.

Comment: so for example the name of my controller is `controllername` all i need to do to my functions is `controllername_get` `controllername_post` etc?

Comment: no must be different, if your controller is called [Test] your method name should be different from your controller name excluding postfix [_get, _post].. example [name_get]. So $this->test->name_get() and not $this->test->test_get().

Answer (score 3):

while calling the method don't use _get,_post .. 
say for example
you have a method  users_get

```
<?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
    require APPPATH . '/libraries/REST_Controller.php';

    class Student extends REST_Controller {
        function __construct() {
            // Construct the parent class
            parent::__construct();
        }

        public function users_get() {
            $this->response("my first api");
        }
    }

?>
```

let us call this method => "your base url"/student/users

Comment: Please provide a description for your answer.

Comment: Actually this works.. .
I have a method called: allUsers_get()
I call it on post man as: https://localhost/myapp/api/Example/allUsers

Answer (score 0):

mention the details you want to fetch from database and enter the correct name in the database file located in */restapi/application/config/database* file and run the code.

*this error occurs due to the incorrect database name*

```
**<?php
  Class category_model extends CI_Model {
      var $table_name = 'category';
     function get_all_categories()
     {
       $this->db->select('name, email');
       $this->db->from($this->table_name);
       return $this->db->get();
     }
 }
?>**
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change your class name to start with capital letter and make sure your file name also starts with capital letter

```
<?php
  Class Category_model extends CI_Model {
      var $table_name = 'category';

     function get_all_categories()
     {
       $this->db->select('*');
       $this->db->from($this->table_name);
       return $this->db->get();
     }
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write below lines in your controller's top section.

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

use Restserver\Libraries\REST_Controller;

require APPPATH . 'libraries/REST_Controller.php';

require APPPATH . 'libraries/Format.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case the problem was with `http`, it should be `https` if your server is `https`.